# DecimalFormat country problems

Tags: android, numberformatexception, decimalformat

I have the following lines of code in my app to round my percentage to a reasonable length;

```
double percentage = ((double)correct*100)/((double)total);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
percentage = Double.valueOf(df.format(percentage));
```

This code works well 99% of the time, but when people from some European countries use this is crashes, giving me a `NumberFormatException`.

This is because when the `DecimalFormat` rounds the double `56.7777`, it rounds it to `56,8`(with a comma), which means that when I try to convert it to a double, a NumberFormatException is thrown.

Is there any way to set a locality to `DecimalFormat` so that I know it will always round to `56.8` and not `56,8`?

Comment: I did consider replacing the comma with a `.`, but am worried about what might happen if a there was a number like 1,000, which would then be turned into 1.000

Comment: What is the purpose of this code snippet? Are you attempting to round to a certain number of decimal places? And what are you doing with the result? Is it used in other calculations or is it just displayed?

Comment: @MonadNewb - yep, I am trying to round a number, and the result is used for both things, it is displayed and used to calculate some other things

Comment: I'm sure you understand the issues with floating point numbers. If not, I suggest that you read up on them. Even after rounding, `percentage` is not guaranteed to hold the exact value that you expect. I have listed a couple of alternative solutions in my answer and suggest that you check out the tradeoffs for each one.

Comment: @MonadNewb - I understand them to the point that I realize after 6 or so decimal places the double will start loosing accuracy, but will that really affect the accuracy of a decimal that will be rounded to one decimal place?(I will read up on floating points however, because my knowledge is very basic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you specify a custom format with your `DecimalFormat` and then parse the resulting `String` using the format specified by the default `Locale`.

You have several options to solve the problem:

1. Use the same `DecimalFormat` object to both format and parse the number.
2. Use a different rounding algorithm. For example:

   ```
   double roundToHundredths(double d) {
       return (int)(d * 100) / 100.0;
   }
   ```
3. Store the number as an `int` in "hundredths". Do your calculations with this `int` and display it as a decimal.
4. Use `BigDecimal` for greater precision.

Note that using a "rounded" number in any further calculations is still tricky since floating point numbers are imprecise. This means that the "rounded" result is not necessarily exact.

Comment: I ended up going for the first option, as per the accepted answer. Fortunately the numbers don't have to be very precise, they are used for calculating a percentage, and an average percentage. I only round to avoid situations like 33.3333333333 and 1.000000000001

Comment: @jcw Note that rounding doesn't eliminate those situations due to the way computers store floating point numbers. It sounds like you should only round the result when you display it and use the "raw" percentages when calculating the average. (Although, mathematically speaking, averaging percentages is very questionable.)

Comment: That sounds like a better idea than what I am doing now, I'll try that instead

Comment: @jcw If I may ask, what is the reason to take the average of the percentages?

Comment: to give the user an idea of how well they have done on average in the past and to allow them to compare it to how well then have just done - that's why I am not particularly concerned about accuracy, most users probably won't notice if their average percentage is 0.3% off where it should be

Comment: @jcw You might want to consider calculating the overall average instead. It sounds like you are writing some kind of grading program. When you average percentages, the average is weighted. For example, say you have a test with 5 questions and a test with 10 questions. If a user misses one question on the first test and two questions on the second test, both tests are scored at 80% and the average is 80%. Note that the questions on the first test are weighted higher in the final average. If you want every question to have equal weight, then you have to calculate (4+8)/(5+10).

Answer (score 2):

Use the same number format to parse data

```
percentage = df.parse(df.format(percentage), new ParsePosition(0))
```

Other solution is to set your own format symbols

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat('#.0', new DecimalFormatSymbols())
```

I recommend first solution. I tested it on locale that uses comma as decimal separator.

Comment: I didn't realize that decimalformat had a directly to double method... that should certainly do it

Answer (score 1):

```
    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale); // Locale.getDefaultLocale()
    DecimalFormat  decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat)numberFormat;
    char separator =decimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator();
    decimalFormat.applyPattern("#".concat(Character.toString(separator)).concat("0"));"
```

You need to get the decimal separator based on the `Locale`

Comment: Okay, that looks promising, I can't really try it in the UK, but I'll see if it functions with my locality.

Comment: You can try to set default locale. `Locale.setDefaultLocale(Locale.UK);` Just for testing purposes.

Comment: @jcw Or if the result isn't displayed, don't rely on the default Locale at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the currency for a test value, then format and find whether there is a comma or . and handle appropriately if ,

DecimalFormat test =  new DecimalFormat("0.00");
test.setCurrency(c);

String testsample = test.format(1.23);
char ch = sample.indexOf(".") > 0 ? "." : ",";

Answer (score 0):

convert the decimal to a string and apply this to it

```
str = str.replaceAll(",","."); // or "\\.", it doesn't matter...
```

it will turn all `,` to `.`

Comment: I did consider replacing the comma with a `.`, but am worried about what might happen if a there was a number like 1,000, which would then be turned into 1.000